# how can i wait until update query updated the collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

- here I am taking all domain from test collection and checking it's working or not by sending HTTPS req and updating status in the same collection.
- problem is when I get the first domain and its checks and updating status at that time I getting the next domain status also so it's throwing a mongo error.
- so I want to know how can I wait until its update status in the collection(when run update query I need to stop checking the domain until it's updated).

```
router.get("/get", function (req, respo) {
  Client.connect(URL, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("gvm");

    dbo
      .collection("test")
      .find({
        $and: [{ IsDeleted: false }, { TrackDomain: { $nin: [null, ""] } }],
      })
      .project({
        ClientID: "$_id",
        _id: 0,
        TrackDomain: 1,
        IsTrackDomainWorking: 1,
      })
      .toArray(function (error, sites) {
        if (err) throw error;
        
        sites.forEach((item) => {
          let TrackDomain = "https://" + item.TrackDomain;
          try {
            let isWorking = false;

            https.get(TrackDomain, async(res) => {
              if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                isWorking = true;
              }
              
              if (isWorking != item.IsTrackDomainWorking) {
                
                dbo.collection("test").findOneAndUpdate(
                  { $and: [{ _id: item.ClientID }, { IsDeleted: false }] },
                  {
                    $set: {
                      IsTrackDomainWorking: Boolean(isWorking),
                      LastUpdatedBy: item.ClientID,
                      LastUpdatedDate: new Date(),
                    },
                  },
                  function (err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    
                    db.close();
                  }
                );
              }
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
        respo.send("done");
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks that you have to use async functions, is you used async?

Like this (an example):

```
// Here async function is created
auth.prototype.processSignIn = async (incomingUser, callback) => {

    var errors = {}

    // await is only can be used when function is async [ This waits for completion of process ]

    const loginQuery = await Accounts.findOne({
        email: incomingUser.email
    })
    
    if(loginQuery != null)
    {

        if(validatePassword(incomingUser.password, loginQuery.password) === true)
        {
            errors.message = 'success'
            errors.user = loginQuery
            // Hide Password
            loginQuery.password = null
            callback(errors)
        }
        else
        {
            errors.password = 'wrong_password'
            errors.message = 'failed'
            callback(errors)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        errors.email = 'wrong_creds'
        errors.message = 'failed'
        callback(errors)
    }

}
```

Comment: where and how can i here?